# Center div on wrapping (when it doesn't fit on the line)

Tags: html, css, centering, word-wrap

I am trying to create this layout using only CSS:

**When title fits:**

[image: sketch 1]

**When title doesn't fit:**

[image: sketch 2]

The btn on the right should be centered if it wraps.

---

I tried this:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
}
.block {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    float: left;
}
.right-block {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Logo</div>
    <div class="block">Title that is too long</div>
    <div class="block right-block">right-btn</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

But obviously, the btn is still on the right after it wraps. Any idea how to center it when it wraps ? And I'd like to avoid javascript.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b7rvhwqg/

Comment: Add clear: both; to your titles css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Pure CSS solution using a flexbox layout:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/c7ufykd4/)

The trick is to add `justify-content: center`/`flex-wrap: wrap` to the parent `.container` element for horizontal centering. Then adjust the first element's `margin-right` value to `auto` in order to prevent the last element from being centered when it's on the same line.

(You may need to resize the browser to see how it adjusts).

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo-text {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
.center-block {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo-text">
    <div class="block logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="block text">This title is short.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block right-block">right-btn</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo-text">
    <div class="block logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="block text">This title is slightly longer than the other one. This title is longer than the other one...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block right-block">right-btn</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue to achieve this via Pure CSS. The div is already having a float and you want to have a "long title" to accommodate that float and at the same time, you want the other right float to jump and become center. This is currently not possible. I believe, you need to consider media queries, but again, that will be a dependent solution, but your title looks like independent of expanding/contracting.

Comment: It's actually possible using a flexbox layout, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33877756/2680216) :)

Comment: I agree @JoshCrozier, but I believe this will not work smooth across all the browsers. BTW, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

is it ok for you if the title will just fit depending on what width u want?.. for example:

{Logo}Title is toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolong {btn}

it will become like this:

{Logo}Title is tooo... {btn}

it will be cut, then only ". . ." will continue

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
}
.block {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    float: left;
}
.ellipsis{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;    width: 75%;
}
.right-block {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Logo</div>
    <div class="block ellipsis">Title that is too long Title that is too long Title that is too long that is too long Title that is too long</div>
    <div class="block right-block">right-btn</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7rvhwqg/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the most suitable for this task:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="block title">Title that is too long Title that is too long</div>
    <div class="block right-block">right-btn</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.block.logo {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
.block.title{
    flex-grow: 10;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
.right-block {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px solid orange; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmrash/7b8w982t/