# Center buttons on wrap only

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with just CSS but so far I haven't really found anything.

I have a few buttons that sit inline with each other inside of a responsive container.

However, when they wrap, and the 2nd button drops to a new line, I would like to then center them. Anyone know if this is possible with just css?

A fiddle showing basically what I'm looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/5bvmnt3j/

In the fiddle pretend the wrapper is responsive and as the browser width changes, and makes the buttons wrap, we get the layout I'm showing in the wrapper2 class instead of what is seen in the original wrapper class.

I know normally this isn't really something you would expect to see with a css only solution but I've seen some pretty cool things with flexbox similar to what I'm asking. (e.g. [Center div on wrapping (when it doesn't fit on the line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877327/css-center-div-on-wrapping-when-it-doesnt-fit-on-the-line))

Hoping to avoid using JS to detect a height change and then toggling a class. Thx.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}
.wrapper2 {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Btn #1</button>
  <button>Btn #2</button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <button>Btn #1</button>
  <button>Btn #2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: One note based on initial answers but I am hoping that until the buttons wrap they sit right next to each other the way you would expect two inline elements to do.

Comment: Media queries, maybe? Otherwise, without js... not sure that there is solution...

Comment: Yeah media queries wont really work for me because of the way the wrapper is used on the page. Thx for the suggestion though. This might not be possible I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with flexbox and a media query:

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bvmnt3j/2/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
}
button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
@media ( max-width: 700px ) {
  .wrapper { flex-direction: column; align-items: center; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Btn #1</button>
  <button>Btn #2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure that flexbox is needed at all, if media queries will be used: https://jsfiddle.net/5bvmnt3j/3/

Comment: @sinisake, flexbox may not be necessary. I used it because the OP seemed to be wanting to learn about flex, and it's a powerful and cutting-edge layout technology.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a media query if the buttons have a fixed width.

https://jsfiddle.net/jaxon58/c0Lsrb7o/3/

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}        
button {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}       
@media(min-width: 420px) {
  .wrapper {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Btn #1</button>
  <button>Btn #2</button>
</div>
```

You will need to tweak the media query and the button widths to get them exact.

Comment: Sorry same point as I left in the other answer and as a comment on my question but if possible I'd like the buttons to originally be left justified until they wrap and then be centered only at that point. Like my original fiddle shows even though I didn't point it out. 

Possible? Thx for this answer though.

Comment: Okay, you can change the alignment when they wrap, if the buttons have constant widths, I have updated my answer and my fiddle